# Everytime i want go to a route path, when an invalid path is given

Tags: ember.js

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router'; 

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({ 
}); 


Router.map(function() { 
  this.route('index', {path: '/templates'}); 
  this.route('show', {path: '/templates/:id'}); 
}); 

export default Router;
```

I want to go to /templates, whenever any invalid path is given like /wrongquery.

Answer (score 4):

Add a [wildcard route](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard--globbing-routes) to the end of your router

```
Router.map(function() { 
    this.route('index', {path: '/templates'}); 
    this.route('show', {path: '/templates/:id'}); 
    this.route('not-found', { path: '/*path' });
});
```

Create a not-found route and use it to [transition](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/redirection/#toc_transitioning-before-the-model-is-known) your users to /templates.

```
export default Route.extend({
    beforeModel() {
        this.transitionTo('index'); 
    }
});
```